# use xcodebuild to creat a CI system, error : "Ld build xxxx normal arm64"

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

Recently I was asked to creat a CI system, so I tride to use xcodebuild.
But I got Errors, the command is :`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release clean build`

> **Errors:**
>   ld: library not found for -lFMDB
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>     Ld build/ProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ProjectName normal armv7
>
> Ld build/ProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProjectName normal arm64

I import FMDB by cocoa pods, and **Header Search Path** has this path `"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FMDB"`.

Please help me,thx very much.

Comment: Hi. Can you show all your CI build steps? I suppose that you should perform a `pods-install`-step before a `xcodebuild`-step.

Comment: @Mozilla Hi~ Here is my steps. Step1: I use Jenkins to get the code from github; Step2: I write a python script to make some channel ipas(use xcodebuild and xcrun command);  `pods install`, I didn't perform yesterday